# If $Y$ is a Markov chain and $h>0$, why is $(Y_{\lfloor t/h\rfloor})_{t\ge0}$ not a Markov process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

Let $\left(Y^{(n)}_k\right)_{k\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a Markov chain for $n\in\mathbb N$, $(h_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq(0,\infty)$ with $h_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty$ and $$X^{(n)}_t:=Y^{(n)}_{\lfloor\frac t{h_n}\rfloor}\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$.

> Let $n\in\mathbb N$. In Remark 2 below Corollary 206 of [these lecture notes](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/754/notes/lecture-15.pdf), the author is noting that $X^{(n)}$ is *not* a Markov process.
>
> I don't get that. If $\mathcal F^Z$ denotes the filtration generated by a process $Z$, we should easily obtain $$\mathcal F^{X^{(n)}}_t=\mathcal F^{Y^{(n)}}_{\lfloor\frac t{h_n}\rfloor}\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag1$$ and $$\operatorname P\left[X^{(n)}_t\in B\mid\mathcal F^{X^{(n)}}_s\right]=\operatorname P\left[X^{(n)}_t\in B\mid X^{(n)}_s\right]\;\;\;\text{almost surely}\tag2.$$ So, $X^{(n)}$ should be a Markov process. What am I missing?

Comment: What does the superscript $(n)$ in the notation $Y^{(n)}_k$ mean?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "not _necessarily_" Markov? An iid sequence is trivially Markovian.

Comment: Also do your lecture notes assume that a "Markov process" must be homogenous in time?

Comment: In particular, note that what Corollary 206 says is that $X_n$ is not a _homogeneous_ Markov process.

Comment: @HenningMakholm No, in Remark 2 they say that it is not a Markov process. Otherwise, the remark would be pointless since clearly even a non-homogeneous Markov chain has a time-evolution operator.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The $(n)$ is just the index of the $n$th Markov chain $Y^{(n)}$. I don't like to write $Y^n$ since it could be confused with the $n$th power.

Comment: @BruceET It's not my wording, but I've meant that the given assumptions don't yield the Markovianess.

Comment: Yes the process is Markov and no, it is not homogeneous Markov. This is exactly what the authors (rightfully) mean.